# Creating statement SQL server and Java

Tags: java, sql, arrays, resultset

I have created a method to retrieve information from a table inside a database.

The method looks like this:

```
public void executeStatement(String SQLstatement) {
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = SQLstatement;
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception se) {
          se.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So far, my method works, but right now, I am just pulling one column from my result set.

However, I would like to store my result set into an array, and then I would like to insert the contents of the array into a table.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can just use a ResultSet and query the entire table, and put them in a set, or an array

```
//Array or set instaniation
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table");

while (rs.next()) {
  String value = rs.getString("value");
  //Do your set or array
}
```

That will get all your rows into an array, or set, whatever.

Then you can just take each value, and insert them into a table, however you want to do that.